# Kotlin idomatic way to get columns of connect four game when hovering over it

Tags: kotlin

I want to realize a game of four . The new chip will hover under the mouse cursor and accoring to its x-coordinates I want to calculate the column over which it hovers atm (and where it will be inserted after a click)
 At the moment I do sth like this:

```
fun whichColumnIsChip(chip : Chip) : Int{
        val x = chip.x/2
        val columnWidth = Chip.radius*2 + distanceBetweenColumns
        val rightColumnBorder = IntArray(gamefield.columns.size){ i -> marginLeft+(i+1) * (Chip.radius*2 + distanceBetweenColumns) }
        when {
            x.betweenInclusive(0.0, rightColumnBorder[0].toDouble()) -> return 0
            x.betweenInclusive(rightColumnBorder[0].toDouble(), rightColumnBorder[1].toDouble()) -> return 1
            x.betweenInclusive(rightColumnBorder[1].toDouble(), rightColumnBorder[2].toDouble()) -> return 2
            x.betweenInclusive(rightColumnBorder[2].toDouble(), rightColumnBorder[3].toDouble()) -> return 3
            x.betweenInclusive(rightColumnBorder[3].toDouble(), rightColumnBorder[4].toDouble()) -> return 4
            x.betweenInclusive(rightColumnBorder[4].toDouble(), rightColumnBorder[5].toDouble()) -> return 5
            x.betweenInclusive(rightColumnBorder[5].toDouble(), rightColumnBorder[6].toDouble()) -> return 6
            else -> return -10
        }
    }
```

So if my cursor hovers over in between the x-coordinates of the 3rd column I just want to return 3

The code above works as intended, but I am sure there is a much more idomatic and shorter way

Comment: What's the exact problem? Doesn't it work? Does it work too slow or inaccurate? Is there any error message?

Comment: It works like intended but is WAY to clunky and Im sure there is a much easier and more idomatic way

Comment: you can either iterate over your column array to cut down on code or simply divide `x` by column width to get current one.

Comment: Could do something like `return try { rightColumnBorder.withIndex().first { (idx, column) -> x >= 0 && x <= column }.index } catch (e : NoSuchElementException) { -10 }`. I'm not sure if this is totally correct, but you get the idea. Using math in this case would be way better though.

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu try to describe your problem as easy as possible... and maybe that description can be helpful for you to identify a more idiomatic approach... For me it sounds like you have a column-width and some x-coordinate... so isn't it just: "x divided by column-width rounded down" (because your columns seem 0-based)? so could it be: `floor(x / columnWidth)`, where `columnWidth` is the total width such a column takes incl. gaps... Why would it ever be `-10`? If you require that too then just handle that case before you do your calculation...

Comment: Why is it `x = chip.x/2`? What is this given chip exactly?

Comment: aah. thats just a quick and dirty fix because the framework I use does report the wrong x coordinate at the moment off by factor 2 due to scaling issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few improvements could be done

1) Since Kotlin's `when` is not only a statement but an expression as well, you can reduce this

```
when {
 condition1 -> return 1
 ...
 conditionN -> return N
}
```

to

```
return when {
 condition1 -> 1
 ...
 conditionN -> N
}
```

2) You can reduce copypaste by declaring a function that performs a check on given array and some index. In following example the function is declared as local in order to capture local variables `x` and  `rightColumnBorder`, but it could be declared as regular or extension, it's up to you.

```
fun option1(): Int {
    //...
    val test = fun (i: Int) = x.betweenInclusive(
                if (i > 0) rightColumnBorder[i - 1].toDouble() else 0.0,
                rightColumnBorder[i].toDouble())

    return when {
        test(0) -> 0
        test(1) -> 1
        test(2) -> 2
        test(3) -> 3
        test(4) -> 4
        test(5) -> 5
        test(6) -> 6
        else -> -10
    }
}
```

However, in your particular case you can notice that returned result is determined by the given array index, so the whole `when` statement could be replaced with a loop:

```
fun option2(): Int {
    //...
    rightColumnBorder.forEachIndexed { idx, value ->
        val from = if (idx > 0) rightColumnBorder[idx - 1].toDouble() else 0.0
        if (x.betweenInclusive(from, value.toDouble())) {
            return idx
        }
    }
    return -10
}
```

OR

```
fun option3(): Int {
    //...
    val test = fun (i: Int) = x.betweenInclusive(
            if (i > 0) rightColumnBorder[i - 1].toDouble() else 0.0,
            rightColumnBorder[i].toDouble())

    rightColumnBorder.forEachIndexed { i, _ -> if (test(i)) return i }

    return -10
}
```